# Fermi-Dirac & Bose-Einstein: ideal gas, or more general?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

The Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein distributions are only for ideal gases or are applicable to more general systems? By *ideal gases* I mean all kind of systems composed by particles that do not interact with one another.

Comment: If you are interested in interacting models for fermions and bosons, I suggest you google *ultra-cold fermions* and *Bose-Einstein condensates*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein distributions are only valid for ideal systems of non-interacting and indistinguishable fermions and bosons, respectively.

However, this does not undermine their importance. Many non-ideal systems can be mathematically transformed to effective problems of ideal non-interacting systems. For example, the thermodynamic behavior of a solid (which is as far from an ideal gas as you can get), is completely captured in a mathematically equivalent model of ideal non-interacting bosons called *[phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon)*; for which a special case of the Bose-Einstein distribution, called the 
[Plank distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), is valid.